# How to convert all switch cases to if else in entire android project

Tags: android, switch-statement, zxing

In my new android App I use "ZXing" for barcode scanning.
so I Imported it in my project. but it has lots of the same error

> As of ADT 14, resource fields cannot be used as switch cases.   Invoke
>   this fix to get more information.

so that I've to manually press (ctrl+1) for every switch case
is there any way to automatically do that for the entire project ?

Comment: Go to your `project.properties` file.
    Delete this line `android.library=true`

Comment: You are not intended to use the `android` module as a library, which is why it does not compile this way. Use `core` and write your own app around it please.

Comment: but "core" is not allowed to be imported. only "android".